# Pymodbus Client setValues limitedto 100 registers

Tags: client, raspberry-pi3, modbus, pymodbus3

I am using pymodbus on a raspberry pi as a client to hold values from senors and make them available to a modbus master over TCP.

All works great. I am using the following to setup the datastore. 
values   = context[slave_id].getValues(register, address, count=350)
The problem is when I try and set the values I can't go over [98] list values.

If I set the count=5 I can set values from [0] to [4] but it throws an error when I set [5] as you would expect.

With the count=350 I get and error when I try and set the value [99].

This would suggest their is a limit of 100 registers. Can this limit be extended?

Looking at store.py I can't see any limitations so I am a bit confused as to where the limit would be set.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit in the Modbus specification of the amount of registers that the protocol can handle. The most I've personally read/write in a single call is 120 register, but here is an explanation on control.com:

"The quantity of registers to be read, combined with all the other fileds in the expected response, must not exceed the allowable length of Modbus messages: 256 bytes."

The Modbus/RTU response to a Function 3 request includes

node address: 1 byte
function code: 1 byte
byte count: 1 byte

register data: N registers * 2 bytes each

CRC: 2 bytes

Therefore, the max number of registers that can be read in a single Modbus/RTU query is 125.

If you use Modbus/TCP, you trade the device address and CRC (total of 3 bytes) for a 6-byte header and a 1-byte unit identifier; the max count of registers in a single response drops to 123.

[Maximum amount of holding registers per request](http://control.com/thread/1026161502#1026161502)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. This is a slave implementation of pyModbus not a master. When I read the registers from my Master I read in blocks of 100 registers as you have said.

Comment: The problem is when you create the data-store of registers in pyModbus it

Comment: Wont let you add values to the slave for more than the first 98 registers.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question. If you are setting up PyModbus to act as a slave and you want over 100 registers available you need to edit the following lines of code in your python script to reflect the quantity of registers you want to update.

This is where you initialize your data store in your python script.

```
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [1]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [2]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [3]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [4]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
```

Change the value 100 to the quantity of registers you want to update.

Thank you StackOverflow and contributors. You are my main goto for finding answers to problems. Great site. Cheers